# Calling other class methods in unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I have a class which contains a list of objects in it, which then uses to return the user a calculated value using these objects' states. E.g:

```
class MyContaier {
    private List<MyObject> m_listOfObjects;

    public MyContainer() {
        ...
    }

    public void addObject(MyObject object) { 
        m_listOfObjects.add(object);
    }

    public int calculateTotal() {
        int total = 0;

        for (MyObject object : m_listOfObjects)
            total += object.getValue();

        return total;
    }
}
```

I am trying to unit test `calculateTotal` method using junit and mockito, but in order to do that I need to add a few mocked MyObject instances to m_listOfObjects. However, this would mean calling another method in the `calculatedTotal` test, `addObject`.

Is this a valid unit test, or is it against the best practices as my test of `calculateTotal` also depends on `addObject` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Unit" test does not mean testing just one class in isolation.
If you can create the objects using simple code I suggest you do that instead of adding Mocks.

Use simple, real objects that represent examples of valid input and you'll get a robust test. Trying to over-mock everything would only result in simple, easily broken and usually useless test.

And yes - it's still a unit test - the unit being calculation of all the values of the objects in question.